# Android canvas not drawing

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I have found very few tutorials on how to use the android canvas. However, after looking at the official documentation I was able to produce this code. I simply would like to draw a green rectangle.

```
public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Object shape;
    Target target;

    Rect r;
    Paint paint;

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        r = new Rect();
        r.set(0,0,c.getWidth(),c.getHeight()/2);

        c.drawRect(r,paint);

        shape = new Shape(30,10);  //Object setup
        //shape.pick(); //Pick random point for target
    }

}
```

I do not want to use a customView to draw, I just want to use pure android canvas. When I run the code I get no errors or any warnings.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Kelton

Comment: You need to draw the canvas onto the view.

Comment: @MatthewHooker Does this mean I have to make a new class that implements view? Or how would I go about doing that?

Comment: findViewById will get you the view. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a Canvas `c` with an underlying Bitmap `b`. Now anything that you draw on the Canvas `c` will actually be drawn on the Bitmap `b`. And you have done the drawing part in the above code. The Bitmap `b` has your drawn rectangle. But now to view that you need to load this Bitmap `b` in some view, like an ImageView. You can have an `ImageView` in your `activity_level` layout and then use `ImageView.setImageBitmap(b)` to load the Bitmap onto the view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following 2 lines at the end:

```
 ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_where_i_will_put_my_awesome_green_rectangle);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ImageView and set the Bitmap as the one you created with canvas.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
addContentView(imageView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
```